# How to add modifiers to methodspec in javapoet?

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

I try to add some modifiers to a methodspec but i'm stuck at the parameters. The parameters are from the type `Modifier`. The tutorial says that you can just pass `Modifier.PUBLIC`but `Modifier.PUBLIC` is an Integer value. Am i missing something here? This is my (equal to the tutorial on github) code:

```
public void generateCode(){
    MethodSpec main = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("main")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
            .returns(void.class)
            .addParameter(String[].class, "args")
            .addStatement("$T.out.println($S)", System.class, "Hello, JavaPoet!")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: `Modifer.PUBLIC` is not an `int`. It's of type `Modifier`, look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Modifier.html?is-external=true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `java.lang.reflect.Modifier.PUBLIC`, which is indeed an `int`, but
JavaPoet wants a `javax.lang.model.element.Modifier`, which is an enum.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe that i didn't check the imports though.